# How do I get hardware info about my laptop camera?

Tags: command-line, hardware, webcam

I want to know if there is any way to extract hardware specific information about the built-in webcam in my system from the Ubuntu command line.

Basically, I want to extract the *field of view* and *focal length* of the camera, to use in another program. Is this info even stored?

Thanks!

Comment: @hg8 Not a duplicate. The linked question only asks to list available webcams, not finding out any other information or hardware specifications about it.

Answer (score 0):

try `lsusb -v`
or `lsusb`

for example:

```
description: Video
                   product: Laptop Integrated Webcam
                   vendor: OmniVision Technologies, Inc. -2640-07.05.16.3
                   bus info: usb@4:6
                   version: 1.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480.0MB/s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [V4L2 API](http://www.linuxtv.org/downloads/legacy/video4linux/API/V4L2_API/spec-single/v4l2.html#camera-controls) from python to get such values, for example:

> **V4L2_CID_EXPOSURE_AUTO**    (enum v4l2_exposure_auto_type)      Enables
>   automatic adjustments of the exposure time and/or iris aperture. The
>   effect of manual changes of the exposure time or iris aperture while
>   these features are enabled is undefined, drivers should ignore such
>   requests. Possible values are:
>   V4L2_EXPOSURE_AUTO    Automatic exposure time, automatic iris aperture.
>   V4L2_EXPOSURE_MANUAL  Manual exposure time, manual iris.
>   V4L2_EXPOSURE_SHUTTER_PRIORITY    Manual exposure time, auto iris. 
>   V4L2_EXPOSURE_APERTURE_PRIORITY   Auto exposure time, manual iris.

And

> **V4L2_CID_FOCUS_AUTO**   (boolean)       Enables automatic focus adjustments.
>   The effect of manual focus adjustments while this feature is enabled
>   is undefined, drivers should ignore such requests.

The following script just gets the two above values but you can use/find more settings in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/v4l2.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import ctypes
import fcntl

_IOC_NRBITS = 8
_IOC_TYPEBITS = 8
_IOC_SIZEBITS = 14

_IOC_NRSHIFT = 0
_IOC_TYPESHIFT = _IOC_NRSHIFT + _IOC_NRBITS
_IOC_SIZESHIFT = _IOC_TYPESHIFT + _IOC_TYPEBITS
_IOC_DIRSHIFT = _IOC_SIZESHIFT + _IOC_SIZEBITS

_IOC_WRITE = 1
_IOC_READ = 2

V4L2_CTRL_CLASS_CAMERA = 0x009a0000
V4L2_CID_CAMERA_CLASS_BASE = V4L2_CTRL_CLASS_CAMERA | 0x900
V4L2_CID_EXPOSURE_AUTO = V4L2_CID_CAMERA_CLASS_BASE + 1
V4L2_CID_FOCUS_AUTO = V4L2_CID_CAMERA_CLASS_BASE + 12

def _IOC(dir_, type_, nr, size):
    return (
        ctypes.c_int32(dir_ << _IOC_DIRSHIFT).value |
        ctypes.c_int32(ord(type_) << _IOC_TYPESHIFT).value |
        ctypes.c_int32(nr << _IOC_NRSHIFT).value |
        ctypes.c_int32(size << _IOC_SIZESHIFT).value)


def _IOC_TYPECHECK(t):
    return ctypes.sizeof(t)

def _IOWR(type_, nr, size):
    return _IOC(_IOC_READ | _IOC_WRITE, type_, nr, _IOC_TYPECHECK(size))


class v4l2_control(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('id', ctypes.c_uint32),
        ('value', ctypes.c_uint32),
    ]

VIDIOC_G_CTRL = _IOWR('V', 27, v4l2_control)

exposure = v4l2_control(V4L2_CID_EXPOSURE_AUTO)
focus_auto = v4l2_control(V4L2_CID_FOCUS_AUTO)
with open('/dev/video1', 'r') as vd:
    fcntl.ioctl(vd, VIDIOC_G_CTRL, exposure)
    fcntl.ioctl(vd, VIDIOC_G_CTRL, focus_auto)
print("exposure auto: %i" % exposure.value)
print("focus auto   : %i" % focus_auto.value)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll check if the info I require can be got through the v4l2 api.